# Access data from base class with the correct typecasting of it derived templated class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have the following scenario:

```
class ScalarField
{
   void* _buffer; //Array for data.
};
```

And a derived class:

```
template <typename T> 
class ScalarFieldT : public ScalarField
{
    ScalarFieldT(int size)
    {
       _data = new T[size];
       _buffer = _data;
    }

   T& get(int index)
   {
       return _data[index];
   }

   T* _data; // Typed array for data
};
```

Notice that `T` can assume only basic types such float, int, double and so on.

This is a very old legacy code, so I don't have too much flexibility to adjust it properly doing a better design. What a need to do is to access the data from `ScalarField::_buffer` with the correct typecasting of it derived class.

Something like this:

```
void main()
{
   int n = TOTAL_SIZE;
   ScalarFieldT<int> typedScalarField(n);

   ScalarField* scalarField = &typedScalarField;

   // This is what I need to do:
   int index = ELEMENT_INDEX;        
   float value = scalarField->method(index); // Get the value from base class correctly converted from int to float, for example.       
}
```

The point is, I only have access to the base class abstraction, but I need to get the value from `_buffer` converted to another simple data type, such float, int, uchar, etc.

What do you guys recommend?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want the `int` to be casted as a `float` in that `main()` example, or do you intend to ensure 100% that `float value = scalarField->get(index);` will only ever be called with a scalarField that is instantiated as a `ScalarFieldT<float>`?

Comment: Use `static_cast`.

Comment: At the point where you have `ScalarField*` in hand, do you know the actual type of the elements that `_buffer` points to? In other words, do you know `T` for `ScalarFieldT<T>` of which this particular instance is a base class subobject? Without that, you are sadly out of luck, I'm afraid. Looking at `ScalarField` alone, you wouldn't be able to tell whether `_buffer` points to an array of `int`s or an array of `float`s - but of course the actual bits in the array would have to be interpreted very differently for these two cases.

Comment: This is the point @IgorTandetnik. With `ScalarField*` in hands I don't have any information about `T`. I'm avoiding to use some upper casting, for example using dynamic_cast, to test it type.

Comment: @Frank, I only need to cast values from `int` to `float` with no explicit conversion like using `dynamic_cast` or something like this.

Comment: So basically, all you have is a `void*` pointer and no idea what it might be pointing to? Then I'm afraid there's nothing useful you can do with that pointer. You'd have to revisit your design.

Comment: Yes @IgorTandetnik =(

Comment: @IgorTandetnik do you have any design suggestion to solve this?

Comment: I don't know enough about the problem you are trying to solve, or constraints you have to labor under, to offer suggestions.

Comment: @JoãoPauloNavarro is [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/C4qly72N3jy1OhbQ) a viable solution? Let me know and I'll put it in an answer if it works for you. It does more or less what you asked for, that is extract the parameter from the underlying buffer, cast it to its original type and then to the requested one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a type that provides a set of cast operators as a return type for `method`.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<memory>

class ScalarField {
protected:
    struct Value {
        virtual operator float() const = 0;
        virtual operator int() const = 0;
        // ...
    };

public:
    virtual const Value & method(int i) = 0;

protected:
    void* buffer;
};

template <typename T> 
class ScalarFieldT : public ScalarField {
    struct TValue: Value {
        TValue(T value): value{value} {}
        operator float() const override { return float(value); }
        operator int() const override { return int(value); }
        // ...

    private:
        T value;
    };

public:
    ScalarFieldT(int size) {
        data = new T[size];
        buffer = data;
    }

    T& get(int index) {
        return data[index];
    }

    const Value & method(int i) {
    std::make_unique<TValue>(data[i]);
}

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Value> value;
    T* data;
};

int main() {
    ScalarFieldT<int> typedScalarField(10);
    ScalarField* scalarField = &typedScalarField;
    float f = scalarField->method(2);
    int i = scalarField->method(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm - please don't throw stones on me for a probably silly answer, but...

Let's assume that `T` is restricted to numeric data types, e.g. `int`, `long`, `double`, `float`, and let's further assume that the largest integral value to be stored is about 2^53. Then `double` could serve as an data exchange data type, to which any other data type can be converted without losing precision.

Then one could define `virtual double ScalarField::method(int index) = 0`, which is then overloaded accordingly in the typed variants, which do an "up"-cast from actual type `T` to double.

Unless you are allowed to encapsulate the values in an object (e.g. struture/class Value), the following code using the "use double as data exchange data type" could work:

```cpp
class ScalarField
{
public:
    void* _buffer; //Array for data.
    virtual double method(int index) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class ScalarFieldT : public ScalarField
{
public:
    ScalarFieldT(int size)
    {
        _data = new T[size];
        _buffer = _data;
    }

    virtual double method(int index) { return get(index); }

    T& get(int index)
    {
        return _data[index];
    }

    T* _data; // Typed array for data
};
```